# Interpreting a PLS-DA model with Caret

Tags: r, regression, structural-equation-modeling, caret, partial-least-squares

I'm train a **Partial Least Squares Discrimination Analysis** with `caret` package.

My dataset dimensions are 80K rows, 50 continuous explanatory variables, and one response called Category (with 7 levels).

```
labelName = 'Category'
predictors = names(train)[!(names(train) %in% labelName)]

model_pls = train(train[,predictors], 
                  train[,labelName],
                  method="pls",
                  trControl=trainControl(method='none'),
                  tuneGrid= expand.grid(ncomp=8))
```

How to interpret the outputs for **PLSDA**? There are many outputs: **scores**, **loadings**, **loading.weights**, ... How to plot the scores within two components or latent variables? Is there any loadings plot function?

I need your help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please do *not* crosspost questions to multiple [se] sites. You have just posted the same thing to [so] not 10 minutes ago: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46119574/429846